# Where am I going wrong in computing the cokernel of this map?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $A:\mathbb {Z^3\to Z^3}$ be the map given by 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
1&2&0\\
1&0&2 
\end{pmatrix}$$
 Then the cokernel of $A$ is $\mathbb Z^3/\text{ Im }A$ which can be found using the Smith normal form of $A$. 
$$A_{SNF}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&2&0\\
0&0&2 
\end{pmatrix}$$

So then the cokernel is $\mathbb {Z\oplus Z_2\oplus Z_2}$.

However $A$ gives an injective map of free $\mathbb Z$ - modules so that $M\cong\text{ Im} A$. Therefore $\text{ Im }A$ is a free submodule of $\mathbb Z^3$ of rank 3. Doesn't this mean that $\text{Coker }A$ shoud be a finite abelian group? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the image of your diagonal matrix is $\Bbb Z\oplus 2\Bbb Z\oplus 2\Bbb Z$. Hence the cokernel is
$$
\frac{\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z}{\Bbb Z\oplus 2\Bbb Z\oplus 2\Bbb Z}\simeq(\Bbb Z/\Bbb Z)\oplus(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)\oplus(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)\simeq\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z
$$